# Rowspan in iText early versions

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

row span is supported since 2.1.6, actually I am using 2.1.4

I know a nested table solve the problem like this one

```
|-----|-----|
|-----|     |
|-----|-----|
```

but not this one

```
|-----|-----|
|     |-----|
|-----|-----|
```

anyone knows how to make the second one?

Comment: What's the code to generate the first one? Why isn't it possible to modify it to get what you want?

Comment: iText 2.1.4 hasn't been supported for a long time. Please stop using it (I'm the copyright owner of iText, so please take my advise).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie yo bruno bro, thanks for the advise. upgrading isn't easy, sigh..... tons of live ones deployed onsite. but yeh I will schedule a upgrading soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iText 2.1.4 hasn't been supported for a long time. Please stop using it